# AS3 SoundChannel Position of audio in function

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, air, scope, soundchannel

I am having issues with variable scope. I know this must be an easy fix but I can't find it.

I need to play sound through a sound channel in a function. Then I need another function to read the sound channel position. But it is not seeing it because of the new var in the function that plays it.  If I play it outside the function I can get the position from another function but if I beging the sound in the function then another function can not read the channel position. How do I fix this.

The Code

```
import flash.filesystem.File; 
import flash.filesystem.FileMode; 
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;

var lastPosition:Number = 0; var CrossAudio = new Sound();
CrossAudio.load(new URLRequest("Cross.mp3"));

function playCross() {

    PapaAudioChannel = CrossAudio.play();


}
bt_play.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playA);

function playA(event:MouseEvent):void    {   
trace(PapaAudioChannel.position);  // Does not work
/// It can't doesn't recognize the PapaAudioChannel because 
 /// it began playing in another function. 

}
```

How can I get the second function to see the position of the audio. I need to start the audio with a play and pause button so the play has to start in a function.

Thanks

Comment: Fixed indentation + renamed `PapaAudio` to `PapaAudioChannel` since `play()` returns a `SoundChannel`

Comment: Thanks Teejay. Actually, my bad. I posted the wrong code. another function needs to call the PapaAudioChannel.position  and its not seeing it since the PapaAudioChannel began playing in a function.

Comment: Actually you were right... it was the delay that was the issue I think.

Comment: Moved my comment to an answer, accept it if you are ok or keep me informed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the sound can start with a little delay, so tracing sound position just after a play() statement is not a good idea.

**EDIT**

By the way, where is `PapaAudioChannel` defined, if it is? *(it should since this is AS3)*

If you define a var in a function, it dies with that function, at the end of function!

So you may want to define `PapaAudioChannel` in the global scope:

```
import flash.filesystem.File; 
import flash.filesystem.FileMode; 
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;

var PapaAudioChannel:SoundChannel; // defines variable

var lastPosition:Number = 0; var CrossAudio = new Sound();
CrossAudio.load(new URLRequest("Cross.mp3"));

function playCross() {

    PapaAudioChannel = CrossAudio.play();

}

bt_play.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playA);

function playA(event:MouseEvent):void {   

    trace(PapaAudioChannel.position);

}
```

Comment: This did it. It was actually where I was calling the function. I called it on a different set of code. Silly me.Thank you.

Comment: Side note: pay attention not to use `PapaAudioChannel` before it is assigned or you will receive a null exception!